# jquery plugin setting object this.method is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

When trying to refer to method inside the current object e.g "this.arr" is not working or if put "settings.arr" also not working how do i refer to a method inside the current object

```
    var settings = $.extend({
        arr: [378,379,311,537,378],
        backgroundColor: "#323232",
        xPadding: 60,
        yPadding: 60,
        max: M.graph.max(settings.arr),
        min: M.graph.min(settings.arr)
    }, $.fn.graphify.defaults, options);
```

i get TypeError: settings is undefined

Comment: you need to share more context to the problem...

Comment: I just want to know how to refer to other elements within the same object it doesn't really need a context

Comment: Do you have arr as global variable or only in settings object? Because it works for me if i using this.property inside the object's function .

Comment: Yes i do have arr as a global variable "var arr = settings.arr" i have changed the arr in the settings to be "array" , but it still isn't working, my code works great with a min and max as global variables but it doesn't give me the option to change it as a plugin that way to a static integer

Comment: have you seen/try example from my answer below? It works fine .

Answer (score 0):

I create some JSFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/xq1xhoxh/) and it works fine, i mean i can use this.arr inside object's function .

```
var obj = {
    option: ["a", "b", "c"],
    secondOption: function () {
        alert(this.option);
    }
}

obj.secondOption();
```